# How to render the values in a parent child relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a django app where the admin can add travel packages. To add the explicit details of the package I created a child that will handle those values. Here is how the code looks like.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['title']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class SafariPackages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='SafariPackages/%Y/%m/%d', null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cost = models.FloatField(null=False)
    days = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    nights = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    exodus = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    telegram = models.TextField(max_length=140, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Safari Package Entry'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Safari Package Entries'

class DayNumber(models.Model):
    daydetails = models.ForeignKey(SafariPackages, related_name='daydetails', default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day_number = models.CharField( max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField (upload_to='SafariPackagesDetails/%Y/%m/%d', null=False, default=1)
    day_description = models.TextField()
```

The views that I have so far look like this

```
def safaripackages_view(request, *args,**kwargs):
    print (args, kwargs)
    print (request.user)

    all_safaripackages = SafariPackages.objects.all()

#Paginator
paginator = Paginator(all_safaripackages, 8)    
page = request.GET.get('page')      
try:
    all_safaripackages = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    all_safaripackages = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    all_safaripackages = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


context = {
'all_safaripackages': all_safaripackages,
}


return render (request, "safaripackages.html", context)

def single_safaripackage(request, post_id):
    safaripackage = SafariPackages.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    return render (request, 'single_safaripackage.html', {'safaripackage':safaripackage,})
```

How do I include the values of the DayNumber model in the single_safaripackage view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accordance to my understanding,you are trying to render the day numbers of the packages from the child model.

The trick is:

"the parent model"."the child model"_set.all()
eg: parent.child_set.all()

*the child model to be lower case all through regardless of its original form in the model.py

Here is the solution to dynamically render a specific package to the browser:

```
def safaripackages_view(request,pk):
    safaripackage = SafariPackages.objects.get(name=pk_test)
    days = safaripackage.daynumber_set.all()
    context = {"days":days,"safaripackage":safaripackage}
    return render(request,'main/single_safaripackage.html',context)
```

Here is the solution to render all packages:

```
def safaripackages_view(request):
    safaripackage = SafariPackages.objects.all()
    days = safaripackage.daynumber_set.all()
    context = {"days":days,"safaripackage":safaripackage}
    return render(request,'main/single_safaripackage.html',context)
```

In your template you can have like a table to render

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>Day Details</th>
            <th>Day Number</th>
            <th>Day Description</th>
          </tr>
{% for day in days %}
          <tr>
              <th>{{day.daydetails}}</th>
              <th>   {{day.day_number}}</td>
              <td>{{day.day_description}}</td>
<td><img src="{% url 'day.image.url' %}" class="templates" alt=""> <td/>
              <tr/>
          {% endfor %}

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def single_safaripackage(request, post_id):
    safaripackage = SafariPackages.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    day_number = DayNumber.objects.filter(safaripackage__id = post_id)
    return render (request, 'single_safaripackage.html', {'safaripackage':safaripackage, 'day_number':day_number })
```